# Is it true that rotation of a chain does not change its homologous class?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

Let $f\colon Δ ^ n \to X$ be a continuous mapping (= a singular $n$-dimensional simplex in $X$), and $α\colon Δ^n \to Δ^n$ some rotation (that is, orientation-preserving isometry) of the standard n-dimensional simplex $Δ ^ n$

Is it true that the chains $α \circ f$ is homologous to the $f$?

Comment: I think you mean $f\circ\alpha$ rather than $\alpha\circ f$.

Comment: @EricWofsey no, I always write composition this way

Comment: @EschatumVerus This will confuse 99.9% of people who write it they other way, though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  In particular, homologous chains must have the same boundary, but the boundary of $f$ will typically not be the same as the boundary of $f\circ\alpha$.  For instance, if you write down what you get for $n=2$ you can see this quite explicitly.  In general, each boundary face of $f\circ\alpha$ will be obtained from some boundary face of $f$ by composing with an orthogonal transformation of $\Delta^{n-1}$, and they will have opposite signs in the boundary sums if that orthgonal transformation is orientation-reversing.  Even when $f$ is a cycle, $f\circ\alpha$ may not be a cycle.  The pairs of boundary faces which cancelled out in $\partial f$ may no longer cancel in $\partial (f\circ\alpha)$ since they may be parameterized differently.

Comment: Of course, homologous chains must have the same boundary! In trying to prove the homologous of these chains, I have used this many times. I'm surprised this obvious refutation did not occur to me. Thanks!